# Problem in constellation diagram

Tags: qpsk, constellation-diagram

In a waveform designing i am getting this type of constellation(image_attached).
Can anyone please tell me why i am getting this type of constellation?
this constellation is after frequency correction.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE! Looks like your demodulation center frequency is off... but this isn't really my area of expertise. Let's see what answers we get.

Comment: Is this supposed to be QPSK? Fading or AWGN channel? Are you sure the transmitted signal is fine (e.g. the EVM is small)?

Comment: @PeterK. is right, there is a bug in your frequency correction code (or circuitry). If you want more useful help, maybe you could explain how you are implementing frequency estimation/correction in your receiver.

Comment: Thanks to All for reply,
but sir,i am also getting a **fully moving Circle** before frequency correction, i mean to say after symbol timing recovery which is also not correct.
@vaz there is no bug in the frequency correction code beacuse i have tested and used this code in other waveforms also there is no issues.

Comment: Is this with OFDM?  Users here could help you a lot more if you gave a bit more details about what is going on, such as any digital filters or analog mixers involved in whatever this is? Also what bandwidth and channel?